# Basic Athentication won't work after deploying a jersey service on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, basic-authentication

I've added a basic authentication to a jersey service and it worked fine, but after deploying this service on tomcat, when I try to access it on the browser, the authentication window pops up, but it does not accept the user name and the password.

Did I do something wrong? Or did I forget something?

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
>
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.webservices.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>

<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>SEND</web-resource-name>
  <!-- <http-method>GET</http-method> -->
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>

</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint> 
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>


</security-constraint>
<login-config> <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method></login-config> 

</web-app>
```

tomcat_users.xml file

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="member"/>
<user username="zakaria" password="zakaria" roles="admin,member"/>
<user username="jaadi" password="jaadi" roles="member"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Did You analyze logs?

Comment: @JacekCz thank you for quick response, i'm a newbie where to find them ?

Comment: c:\program files...\Tomcat \ logs

Comment: @JacekCz : thank u, here is what i found :  the admin security role name is used in a <auth-constraint> without having been defined in <security-role>. i will edit my question so you could see the web.xml, and tomcat_users.xml file.

Comment: You need to make sure to have [configured the realm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#UserDatabaseRealm) then specify that realm in the web.xml